# Creating a chart using data from two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns with data. One column for Y-axis, another for X-axis. How can I create a chart using this data? Range is different (from 10 cells to 3000).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: each column has a different row count, or at different times both of the columns can have different row counts but both columns will always have the same row count as each other? Perhaps [Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X and Y axis you have different property .values and .xvalues see more here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197014.aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821866.aspx. There is nothing more to tell, but if you dont understand something try to ask.

Comment: Thanks for help! I have a problem with a range. It differs but it depends on `numbShag`. I tried to use `mainChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(1).Range("F1:F" & numbShag)` but I have an 1004 error.

Comment: Solved. Forgot about `mainChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries`